# Xpath between 2 texts for IMPORTXML formula

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have worked out xpath which gives very close to what I need but needs some small refining.

https://www.punters.com.au/form-guide/

I want all URLs from the website racing Today and only in Australia

These are the xpaths I have now.

1. This one provides all the races on the page. Including all countries racing today. - //*[@class='component-wrapper form-guide-index']/table[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPnph.png)/tbody/tr//td/a/@href
2. This one provides all races in Australia. But includes races today, tomorrow or any other day on the webpage - //tr[@class="upcoming-race__row"][preceding::tr[@class='upcoming-race__row upcoming-race__row--country'][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPnph.png)[*/.="Australia"]]/td[position()>=2]/a/@href

[image]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the result you expect from `all URLs from the website racing Today and only in Australia`. So can you explain about it using the sample Spreadsheet or others?

Comment: Tanakie, I need the URLs of the table shown above. The xpaths i posted give the urls i need but includes data outside the markedup table. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about the result you expect from your replying. But I noticed that an answer has already been posted. It will resolve your issue.

Comment: The answer did not resolve the issue. Here is the link to the sheet if it helps to understand.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Me-Jo1zIXLCxc4lyLduifsKOFTiGKD82zoYfQdzSBzU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK. So this is the related topic :
[xpath to obtain texts between 2 tags in IMPORTXML formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60577160/xpath-to-obtain-texts-between-2-tags-in-importxml-formula/)

To get the links of all races in Australia today (replace " with ' in GoogleSheets) :

```
//tr[@class="upcoming-race__row"][preceding::td[@class="upcoming-race__country-title"][1][.="Australia"]][preceding::h2[1][.="Today"]]/td[position()>=2]/a/@href
```

Alternative XPaths :

```
//h2[.="Today"]/following::table[1]//tr[@class="upcoming-race__row"][preceding::td[@class='upcoming-race__country-title'][1][.="Australia"]]/td[position()>=2]/a/@href

//div[@class="component-wrapper form-guide-index"]/table[1]//tr[@class="upcoming-race__row"][preceding::td[@class='upcoming-race__country-title'][1][.="Australia"]]/td[position()>=2]/a/@href
```

Comment: The XPath works (just updated your sheet). I added two more just in case. Don't forget to replace " with ' in GoogleSheets.